# Awk not assigning value of field to variable

Tags: awk

Awk is not assigning the value of a field in my text file to a variable. This is what I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","};
{ a=$6;
print $a;
}' /location/canzee/textfile.txt
```

It's printing all fields in all lines, instead of just the 6th field in all lines. Whereas, if I do this, it prints the 6th field in every line:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","};
{ print $6;
}' /location/canzee/textfile.txt
```

Can someone pls help?

Comment: You can safely remove all commas from your script too, btw.

Comment: @MarkSetchell s/commas/semi-colons/g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$a` doesn't mean what you think it means.  You just want to use `print a`, not `print $a`.  For example, if `a` contained the value `3`, then `print $a` would print field 3.  In your case, `a` probably contains a non-number, in which case the numerical value of `a` is zero, so it prints `$0`, meaning the whole line.

Comment: @Canzee: To concatenate strings, you don't use `+`.  `+` is just for numerical addition.  If you want  to concatenate strings, just put the two strings next to each other.  For example `aint = a"%y%m%d"`.

Comment: I dont want to concatenate.. I want to convert the timestamp which is in 6th field to an int.. For example, I have Thu Jul  3 09:39:09 PDT 2014 in the 6th field.. I want it to be converted to an integer like this 20140703093909

Comment: @Canzee: You don't need to do anything special then.  Strings will automatically be converted to integers whenever you use them like integers.  If you want to make sure the string is converted to an integer, you can add zero to it:  `aint = a+0`.

Comment: @Canzee: In awk, you use `>` for a greater-than comparision:  `if (a>yestint) print a`.